# python subprocess for user input

Tags: python, subprocess, pipe

I want to get user input from a subprocess in an new terminal.

```
    import subprocess
    additionalBuildArguments = "defaultarg1"
    proc = subprocess.Popen(["python", "user_input.py", additionalBuildArguments],
                            creationflags=subprocess.CREATE_NEW_CONSOLE,
                            stdout=subprocess.PIPE, stderr=subprocess.PIPE)
    try:
        outs, errs = proc.communicate(timeout=15)
    except subprocess.TimeoutExpired:
        proc.kill()
        outs, errs = proc.communicate()
    additionalBuildArguments = outs or additionalBuildArguments
```

user_input.py:

```
import sys

arg = sys.argv[1]
user_input = input(f"Additional build arguments [{arg}] (Push <ENTER> to use these settings):\n")
print(user_input)
```

as long as I don't set the **stdout=subprocess.PIPE** and/or the **stderr=subprocess.PIPE** options I can enter input. But with these options I can't write any input to the console.
Indeed I need these options to redirect the stdout, to have access to the printed **user_input** in the parent process.
Does anyone know what's the problem here?

Comment: It's really unclear what you are trying to ask. Is there a reason you are running `python` as a subprocess of itself in the first place? The preferred solution is usually to `import` the function(s) you want to use from the other file, and run them directly.

Comment: The python code I am running is a gdb extention script. I use gdb inside of eclipse and the stdin and stdout of gdb somehow isn't redirected to the eclipse console. So I have two options for a workaround to get user input here. The first one is to use some kind of input dialog but I don't found any platform independent solution without using external packages, which I don't want to. So I'm trying to spawn a new termial, which I can interact with and get the user input from there. But this is not working so far.

Comment: There are many undeclared variables here. Can you try to reduce to a [mre] which is actually runnable and demonstrates your problem?

Comment: I changed the code a little bit. Now all variables should be declared. Basiacally I want to spawn a subprocess and get user input using the **input()** function after that I want to print the user input to stdout which I redircted to the parent process and therefore can read it in the parent process using **outs, errs = proc.communicate(timeout=15)**

Answer (score 1):

Please note that I do not understand why you want to do this, and feel instinctively that you should not.  However, it's perfectly possible: just catpure only *stdout*:

```py
import sys
from subprocess import run
print("Type away: ", end="")
sys.stdout.flush()
r = run(["python", "-c", "print(input())"], capture_output=True, encoding="utf8")
print(f"You entered {r.stdout}")
```

**EDIT** Apparently you are using windows.  Per the docs your flag is set when `shell=True`.  With `shell=True` this works for me, but I have no idea whether it will for you:

```py
import sys
from subprocess import run
print("Type away: ", end="")
sys.stdout.flush()
r = run("python -c 'print(input())'", capture_output=True, shell=True, encoding="utf8")
print(f"You entered {r.stdout}")
```

This can be chained to run in yet a *third* process, which would be needed to print whilst also capturing stdout, from a subprocess.  But at this point we are in the realm of **very horrible hacks**.

A better, but still hacky, solution, is to re-phrase the problem a bit.  You want to spawn a terminal, which apparently you can do, and the user can interact with it correctly, and then you want to get output from that terminal in the spawning code.  *STDOUT* is not the proper channel for this communication.  Personally I would structure my code like this:

in spawning code:

- generate parametrised script to run in spawned terminal and save it as a temp file
- spawn subterminal running the generated script
- wait for completion
- read temp out file and get data
- delete both temp script and temp out file

in generated code:

- do as much as possible (you have a full python, after all)
- dump output as json to a temporary file

This is still hacky, but it only involves spawning *one* terminal.  Note that I still don't understand why you want to do this, but this should at least *work*.

Comment: the problem is that I have to spawn a new terminal with the **creationflags=subprocess.CREATE_NEW_CONSOLE** option, because I can't access the console of the parent process. That's the reason I want to use a subprocess to get the user input. If I try ** r = subprocess.run(["python", "-c", "print(input())"], creationflags=subprocess.CREATE_NEW_CONSOLE, capture_output=True, encoding="utf8"))** it is not working.

Comment: this message **print("Type away: ", end="")** should also be printed in a new spawned terminal because printing to the console in the parent process also does not work. I basically want to emulate an input dialog using a new terminal which is closing after the user entered his input. I want to do that because I cannot use a external lib like Tkinter.

Comment: see updated answer

Comment: Thank you I will try that! I tried to expain a little bit why I want to do that in a comment under the first answer. I know that this is not clean code but I don't exactely understand why I have the problems with stdin and stdout in my python gdb extension when I run it in eclipse, so I'm trying to find a workaround